# jquery organization chart plugin add drag and drop event

Tags: jquery, charts

I want to create an Organization Chart with Drag and Drop functionality. For this I have been using Jquery Organization Chart Plugin.

The chart will create as per my requirement but the problem is when I drop a text in the first node and then try to create another node the text will be remain as it is.

I want to store the dropped data into an array. So, basically want to store data into an array.

Comment: Can you show some code?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/63f6uaga/7/
This is the sample link please provide me the solution of above question. How can i drag the left panel list text to the boxes.

Answer (score 0):

```
I think you should try this one
```

https://jsfiddle.net/dabeng/vfjtyac7/